# Unable to read settings from app.Config

Tags: c#

I have an addin that is installed on various user's machine and on most it is working fine.
But for few users it is unable to load the settings from config file.
The file name is `xxAddin.dll.config` and it has some key and values pairs.
eg

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?
configuration
  appSettings
    add key="KeywordDBPath" value="somepath" 
    add key="keywordServer" value="someserver" /
  /appSettings
/configuration
```

For most of the machines this is installed on, it works fine. But for few users the key values return `null`.

I have checked for config file in the installation folder and it exists and has the same contents. 
To be sure that installation was not corrupt, the application was installed again but no success.

I have tried looking up on various forums but none of the suggestions has helped so far.
Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code that you tried. Did you use System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager class?

Comment: do all the pc's have the right version of .Net installed?

Comment: "Please add the code that you tried. Did you use System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager class?"                                                               Yes.. I used the above mentioned class. Here is a sample from code                                                                 public static string keywordServer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keywordServer"];

Comment: "do all the pc's have the right version of .Net installed? "                                                                      I will have to check that. In the solution dependancies .net framework launch properties has version 4 client Profile Installed..

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess but if it works for WinXP users and not for vista or Win7 users it's because of the user permissions but this should give a exception in your application. Are you swallowing the exception?